# Route to non-empty default route in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

One way to define a default routes with the new RC router is

```
@Routes([{ path: '/',  component: Home }])
```

but how can I show initially a page with a non-empty path? like

```
@Routes([{ path: '/home',  component: Home }])
```

that will never show the home content, but I want it.

How can this be done in the new RC1 router ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**>= RC.4**

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
{ path: '/home',  component: Home }
```

**<= RC.2**

`useAsDefault` is not yet supported in the new router. Create a dummy component for the `/` route that forwards to `/home`

```
export class DummyComponent {
  constructor(private router:Router) {
    setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate('/home'));
  }
}
```

There is also currently no option to skip adding the navigation to the history which might cause issues with the back button.

The router issues are being worked on...

Comment: I think `setTimeout()` is not necessary (after some recent tests).

Comment: I stopped using angular 2 due to the latest router rc1 drama... thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

with rc4 you can use wildcard routes like this

`{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'link/to/default/route' }`